# How to make buttons to interact with leaflet markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've a leaflet map with a marker layer and when you click the marker it pops out a picture besides the map. What I'm trying to do is to make previous and next marker buttons so that the functionality is same when clicking the marker, but I don't know how to make it

Here is the code which generates the markers

```
var selectedMarker = false;
L.geoJson(fi_markers, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);

     marker.on('click', function (e) {
        var feature = e.target.feature;
        var content = '<iframe width="700" height="700" frameborder="0" src="/81_001/'  + feature.properties.pano + '">';
        document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = content;

        if(selectedMarker != false) {
            selectedMarker.setStyle({ fillColor: "#ff7800"});
            }
        marker.setStyle({ fillColor: "#000000"});
        selectedMarker = marker;
        });

    return marker;              
       }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to decide what previous and next means on your map ...

This will tell you which marker has to be selected

Then, when 'previous' button is clicked:

```
selectedMarker.closePopup();
selectedMarker = prevMarker;
selectedMarker.openPopup();
```